# latexmk pointing to a line of code with an error that I don't see

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, warnings, latexmk

When trying to compile my code, latexmk keeps hitting me with an undefined control sequences.  I have checked above, below, and the line it says is causing the issue, but I don't see anything wrong.

Warning message:

```
./230OrbitalMechanicsNotes.tex:969: Undefined control sequence.
l.969         \draw
                   [-latex](-2,0) -- (2,-2) node[right, scale = .75] at (0,-.9)
```

Code snippet:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45]
        \draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
        \draw[dashed, -latex] (-1.5,-2) -- (2,-2) node[below, scale = .75]
        at (0,-2) {\(v_{\venus} = 35.022\)};
        \draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (-1.5,-2) node[left, scale = .75] at (-1.7,-1)
        {\(\nu_2\);
        \draw[-latex](-2,0) -- (2,-2) node[right, scale = .75] at (0,-.9)
        {\(v_2 = 12.9005\)};
        \draw[red] (-1.3,0) arc (0:-40:.44) node[right, scale = .75]
        at (-1.2,-.2) {\(\sigma_2 = \frac{\pi}{9}\)};
        \draw[green] (1.5,-2) arc (180:140:.35) node[left, scale = .75]
        at (1.4,-1.8) {\(\sigma_2\)};
        \draw[blue] (-1.5,0) arc (0:-80:.48) node[right, scale = .75,
        fill = white] at (-1.8,-.6) {\(\varphi_2 = 68.2036\)};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

I dont see any missing `;`, `(`, `(`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`.

Comment: Voting to close this as *Too Localized* as "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{\(\nu_2\);
```

There is no closing `}`.

Comment: thanks I have wasted a lot time trying to figure this out.